# Looping through an investment strategy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, finance

I've created an investment strategy that I would like to loop through for each starting date in the data set.  For example the first cell would be the future return if the strategy was started on 12/31/15, and the second cell would be the future return if the strategy was started on 1/1/16. As long as I can get an ending value I shouldn't have a problem getting the return in % terms. My code so far has not been successful. Below is the part of my code that is trying to accomplish this. I'm currently getting incorrect values for my future returns.

```
value = []
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    df.loc[l[i], 'S&P Future Return'] = sum(value) 
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        value.append(df.loc[l[i], 'Returns'])
```

Comment: I would recommend taking at look at the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From the code you posted it's not clear what the problem is, or what you're trying to accomplish. Are you getting an error, or a different output than you expect?

Comment: I'm getting incorrect values. My goal is for the output to go something like this. If you invested on 12/31/15 your future return would be XX%.  But my code is just adding the same value over and over.

Comment: @Evy555 before we can help you, we'll need a MCVE with sample input and expected values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, since you have a logic error and it's not entirely clear what the logic is supposed to be. Tossing this into Python with an absolute bare bones set of inputs, I get:

```
f = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
g = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

value = []
for i in range(1,len(f)):
    f[i] = sum(value) 
    for i in range(1,len(g)):
        value.append(g[i])

print(f)
```

---

```
[0, 0, 6, 12, 18]
```

By "adding the same value over and over," are you talking about sum(value) increasing by the same amount each loop? Each time, your second for loop appends the contents of the same cells to value: [(l[1],l[2],l[3], ... l[len(l)], 'Returns'] in your code or [2, 1, 2, 1] in my example.

If this what's intended or I'm misinterpreting your code, try giving us some example to go by. No need to give away your investment strategy (though some amount of context always helps), throw some random inputs into the code snippet, and give us the output along with what you expected it to be.